# How can I install Ubuntu 10.10 from HDD/ CD while running Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, 9.10

I am running Ubuntu 9.10 and have downloaded the iso for Ubuntu 10.10. I wish to install Ubuntu 10.10

My Question:
1. Can I install Ubuntu 10.10 as an upgrade over 9.10, so as not to worry about installing drivers and existing apps.
2. Can I install from CD burnt from the 10.10 iso while running ubuntu 9.10
3. Can I install Ubuntu 10.10 to a different partition, do I get the option to create a partition during setup?
4. Can I install Ubuntu 10.10 from the iso while running 9.10, without having to burn to a DVD or a USB

If yes, how?

I am asking these questions because, I tried the upgrade option in 9.10 and it gave me the 10.04 upgrade option, which warned me that Bluetooth and a whole bunch of apps won't work with 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not upgrade from 9.10 to 10.10, you can upgrade from 9.10 to 10.04 and then from 10.04 to 10.10 using the normal upgrade method. You can even use a CD instead of downloading packages for the upgrade.

What I believe you want to do is record the installed applications and reinstall from scratch. Making sure you have backups of all your data first.

Do a search for `dpkg --get-selections` to record and then reimplement your system installed programs.

Comment: I didn't know you could 'record' your installed apps in such a way. Will I be able to re-install the bluetooth and other device drivers once I am done? Ubuntu says that it won't be officially supported in 10.04

Comment: Apps which have been removed won't be installable by default. But it might be possible to install some of them using alternative means. It's better if you post these questions as questions instead of comments so others can answer.